# Regular Expression to match the string pattern with some example custom email domains and some exception?

Tags: regex, powershell

I am building a Regular Expression to catch the string like below:

These are the string that I'd like to catch or match:

```
https://southbeachfutons.in.net/css/upxx/?vfy!=IT.Admin@domain1.com
https://globosum.gb.net/js/0965/?qled!=Web.Admin@domain2.org
https://teandpaper.gb.net/img/654/?qled!=IT.Helpesk@domain1.net
https://babyforum.in.net/css/465/?apc1=Manager.DL@domain1.com
```

This string is safe or does not need to be matched (exceptions):

```
https://go.veeam.com/subscription-preferences.html?mkt_tok=mkaks444KMK2da472hwi3yuo5iufgshjkldfg76asd7gfd635423Bsda33nh8j8e312w34i987yt&DynamicEmail=Vong.Cin@domain1.net
```

By after trying a little bit of myself, I came up with this:

```
\!\=.{1,25}\@(domain1.com|domain1.net|domain2.org)
```

However, it is failing when the email address is longer than 25 characters and the pattern is on the safe list.

Comment: Are you trying to limit the part before `@`? Try [`^[^\s@]{1,70}@(domain1\.com|domain1\.net|domain2\.org)`](https://regex101.com/r/VgiCUG/1).

Comment: What makes one string "safe" and the other not? What are your distinguishing criteria?

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I just wanted to mark any URL which specifically retrieve my email company addresses in the parameter query. So I can mark it as potentially malicious email.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Right, but _why_ is your "safe" example "safe"? It has `domain1.net` as a mail domain just like one of the ones you say you want to match

Answer (score 0):

I've got this string:

```
[.^\/].{0,5}.\=[^=]+\@(?:domain1\.net|domain1\.com |(domain|domains)\.com)
```

which works for the few lines of URL, but somehow failing for the below legitimate email body:

Example email body 1:

```
Account Summary &#126; Amount calculated is based on the total sum of the savings or earnings on each of the products shown in the "My Offers" section of your Shopping Rewards online account. 
http://click.email.shoprewards.com/?qs=55893b3eff016662fbcb5131b282b9b40c4b7a2c7e21dafe299ae3 
Click here to see these offers.

 This is a system generated email sent to Dean.Lombardo@domain1.com. Please do not reply. You're receiving this email because you're a member of the Shopping Rewards loyalty program. Don't miss out on exclusive offers
```

Example email body 2:

```
  (42.6 /2= $21.30).

[cid:43CD7C39-DC53-4630-960C-A4D7FAAE918D]

That's for the salary per hour for the user Preeta.Akshay@Domains.com
```

Example email body 3:
    Message Body
    Website: http://SAI.global.com/urlwrap/?q=AbVtLSw&Zwww.passengertransport.com

```
From:  <mailto:Danielle@passengertransport.com>Danielle@passengertransport.com < <mailto:Danielle@passengertransport.com>Danielle@passengertransport.com> 
Sent: Monday, 17 September 2018 11:11 AM
To: Cathy < <mailto:Cathy@domains.com> Cathy@domains.com>
```

So how to fix that?